# I want to find the path of the folder

Tags: reactjs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPD57.png

This program is part of'REACT'.
Obviously there is a folder called section, but in'App.js' it says that it cannot be found.
Could you please solve this phenomenon?
The installed plugin is'react-router-dom'.
I haven't installed anything else.

Comment: By default you can only load a path like that if there's an index.js file in that folder. It looks like you want something like `import main from './section/main.js'`

Comment: Additionally, please read this entire page. Don't include code in images. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you for telling me.
As I made it myself without looking at the internet, I set the location of'index.js' incorrectly.
Thank you very much. I am learning on my own and it has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can import your file directly like below

```
import main from './section/main.js';
```

Or you can create and index.js file within the section folder and export any function you want.

```
import main  from './main.js';
import content from './content.js';


export { main, content };
```

And import using the folder

```
import { main, content } from './section';
```